# Scanner to byte[]?

Tags: java, byte, java.util.scanner

I have to copy txt file to RAM(use ByteArrayOutputStream), next to make a list with all of the words and number of repeats. 
But when I try print that list, it print me

> "java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match
>   valid=false][need input=false][source
>   closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\ ][decimal
>   separator=\,][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive
>   suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]

I found here where is the problem(That Scanner is not a String Object)but can't find a solution.

Could u check my code and help? 
{

public class JavaRam {

```
File f;
byte [] bTab;
Scanner sc;
String tempLine;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos;

StringTokenizer st;

long startTime=0;
long stopTime=0;


HashMap<String,Integer> hm;



JavaRam(String fileName) throws IOException{


    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    loadFile(fileName); //load file to ram
    System.out.println("Czas ladowania  pliku:  "+ (stopTime=System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));

    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    hm=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    makeList();
    System.out.println("Czas tworzenia listy  wyrazow:  "+ (stopTime=System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));

    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    printing();
    System.out.println("Czas drukowania listy  wyrazow:  "+ (stopTime=System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));


    exit();

    System.exit(0);

}

void loadFile(String fileName){
    try{
    f=new File(fileName+".txt");
    sc=new Scanner(f);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    tempLine=new String(sc.toString());
    bTab=tempLine.getBytes();
    baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try{
    baos.write(bTab);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

void makeList(){
    st=new StringTokenizer(baos.toString());
    Integer ti;                     //temporary int
    for(String nt=st.nextToken(); st.hasMoreTokens()==true;nt=st.nextToken()){
        if(hm.containsKey(nt)==false){
            hm.put(nt, 1);
        }
        else{
            hm.put(nt,(Integer)hm.get(nt)+1);
        }
    }

}

void printing(){
    String sl="Slowo";
    String lp="Liczba powtorzen:";
    String sl1="";
    String lp1="";
    for(String str:hm.keySet()){
        sl1=sl+str;
        lp1=lp+hm.get(str).toString();
        System.out.printf("\n   %-20s,  %-20s",sl1,lp1);
    }
}

int exit() throws IOException{
    baos.close();
    sc.close();

    return 1;
}

public static void main(String []args){
    try {
        JavaRam a=new JavaRam("JPJMMWKM");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

}

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Is i shorter way to fix it than copy from file(with scanner) to byte[] as sign by sign(for loop> scanner.next() etc...)

Answer (score 2):

`tempLine=new String(sc.toString());` that seems wrong; you probably wants `sc.nextLine()`.

Anyway, your code is really confusing. The code in the constructor should be go into another method, too much instance members, etc, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not easy like this. It was just a try to fix (check) it.
But thanks for efforts:)